# Stops setInterval for the first time when pressing the second button

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

When I press a button, setInterval will work. If I want to stop the setInterval command on the first press of a button And let the second button work in setInterval as before. What should I do? The problem now is when pressing the first button. And press the second button to work simultaneously.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  var obj_name = $(this).attr('name');
  if (obj_name != undefined) {
  
    setInterval(function() {
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        method: 'POSt',
        data: {
          obj_name: obj_name,
          time: time
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      method: 'POSt',
      data: {
        obj_name: obj_name,
        time: time
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="submit" name="sub-register">Register</button>
  <button name="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. But it's a lot better to have separate event handlers for each button instead of providing a global event handler and checking the name of the button with an if statement to perform the relevant logic.

Comment: I'm really sure that neither of those buttons stop that `setInterval` from executing.

Comment: i.e. $("[name]='sub-register'").click(...)

Answer (score 0):

Save the `setInterval` in a global attribute like:

```
var globalInterval = setInterval(function() {
   var date = new Date();
   var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
   ....
   ....
}, 1000);
```

And then, you can cancel the interval with [`clearInterval(globalInterval)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

But why wouldn't you seperate the click events to two seperate functions?, the `submit` button would trigger the `setInterval` and save it in a global variable, and the `cancel` will clear it, I think it would make it easier for you to write the functionality.

If you decide to stick with your solution, you can set the Interval inside the

`if (obj_name != undefined)` , and clear it with a `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use clearInterval. Let me make an easy example for you.

```
<div>
    <button type="submit" id="RegisterButton" name="sub-register">Register</button>
    <button name="cancel" id="CancelButton">Cancel</button>
</div>

<script>
    var timer;
    $("#RegisterButton").on("click", function() {
       timer = setInterval(function() {
           //AJAX CALL
       },1000);
    });

    $("#CancelButton").on("click", function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    });
</script>
```

when clicking on register button it will start the interval and on clicking the cancel button it will clear the interval and the timer will stop.

good luck and have fun.